# How can I dynamically filter for dates using mongodb?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, postgresql, mongodb-query

I have the following in postgresql:

```
where("booking.started_at + (interval '1 min' * booking.duration) <= ?", Time.zone.now)
```

However, I don't know how to express it in mongo. I've seen some posts suggesting to use date ranges, something like:

```
db.bookings.find({"started_at": {"$gte": started_at_value, "$lt": ?}})
```

Basically, I'd like to find all the bookings that are started, this means (pseudocode) : `started_at <= current_time <= started_at + duration` . I don't know how to specify the end range of the query. Any pointers?

Comment: Okay so postgresql uses SQL which is a string you need to construct and yes SQL supports parameter binding. But Ruby is a dynamic language as is the concept behind most ORM's using a dynamic data construct to form a query. MongoDB just uses the dynamic data construct without translation to a SQL string. So why can you not just interpolate a variable or "cook" the data structure? That's what I do. All the code I have written cannot be wrong. You got +10 rep for this from someone as of writing, so you probably don't really want to delete it though.

Comment: Could you include a sample document from your collection in MongoDB?